# While loop doesn't break if there is no input

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I want to leave the while loop if the user doesn't input any value. But, when the user doen't input anything, nothing happens, and it also doesn't seem to exit the while loop, because it doen't print the end statement.

I tried to make an if statement that says if the length of the input is equal to 0, valid becomes false. Here's my full code.

```
boolean valid = true;
        String exp =" ";
        while(valid) {
            System.out.println("CS211 Spring Quarter 2023");
            System.out.print("Enter a math expression : "); 
            exp = s.next();
            if(exp.length()==0) {
                valid = false;
                
                
            }           
            //only when the expression is valid, the code proceeds to convert it to postfix, and evaluate the expression            
            if(evaluationofexpression.evalexpress(exp)) {
                 System.out.println();
                 String postfix = infixtopostfix.infix2postfix(exp);             
                 String evaluated = String.valueOf(evalpostfix.evaluatePostfix(postfix));                
                 System.out.println("infix expression:"+ exp);
                 System.out.println("postfix expression:"+ postfix);
                 System.out.println("evaluated expression:"+ evaluated);
                 System.out.println();
            }
            //if the expression is false, it will ask you to try again and repeat the code
            else {
                System.out.println("Try again");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("bye");
```

Comment: `next` is going to wait for a valid input, or as the docs say *"Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true."* - so a "empty" (or new line) input is not valid in this case.  Consider using `nextLine` instead

Answer (score 1):

The *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class uses a delimiter to capture the values returned by the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* method.

The JavaDoc for *Scanner* states the following.

> *A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. ...*
>
> ... *The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by [Character.isWhitespace()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))*

So, I presume you're expecting that when the enter-key is pressed, a newline should terminate the process.

This is not the case—since the *Scanner* will have not captured a delimiter, yet.

If you're looking to capture the entire line provided by the user, and not just one value at a time, use the *[Scanner#nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())* method.

This will be effective when checking for a length of 0.

Thus, assigning *false* to *valid*, and exiting the loop upon the re-iteration  evaluation.